# fire a function each 15 minutes by quarter of hours

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have this function that runs every hour:

```
    (function worker() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'retrieve_wf.php',
            type:"POST",
            data: {hk: "<?php echo $hk; ?>"},
            success: function(data) {
                infoes = data.split("|");
                var layout = infoes[0];
                var id = infoes[1];
                if(layout==0){
                    $('.scheda').hide();
                    $('#0').show();
                }else if(layout==1) {
                    //ho scelto il layout video + testo
                        $.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            url: 'retrieve.php',
                            data: {layout: layout, id: id},
                            success: function(data){
                                data1=data.split("|");
                                $('#coldx p').html(data1[0]);
                                $('#colsin video source').attr('src', data1[1]);
                                $("#colsin video")[0].load();
                                $('#riga>marquee').html(data1[2]);
                                /*$('#riga').marquee({
                                    speed: 5000,
                                    gap: 50,
                                    delayBeforeStart: 0,
                                    direction: 'left',
                                    duplicated: true,
                                    allowCss3support: true
                                });
                                */
                            },
                            complete: function(){
                                $('.scheda').hide('fast');
                                $('#'+layout).show('fast');
                            }
                        });
                }else if(layout==2) {
                    //ho scelto il layout testo a tutto schermo
                        $.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            url: 'retrieve.php',
                            data: {layout: layout, id: id},
                            success: function(data){
                                $('#testo_grande').html(data);
                                },
                            complete: function(){
                                $('.scheda').hide('fast');
                                $('#'+layout).show('fast');
                            }
                        });
                }else if(layout==3) {
                    //ho scelto il layout con dati esterni
                    //code
                }    
            },
            complete: function() {
              // Pianifico la funzione per ripartire dopo un'ora (dovrei forse mettere qualche secondo di più)
              setTimeout(function(){setTimeout(function(){location.reload();},10000)},3600000 - ((new Date) % 3600000));
            }
        });
    })();
```

I can open the page at any time so I had to set it in order to do the first reload at the exact hour (so for example if I open the page at 8:36 it will do the first reload at 9:00 and then each hour and not at 9:36 and so on).

Now the requirement is to do the same but with quarter of an hour. So if I open the page at 8:36 the first reload should be at 8:45 and then 9:00, 9:15, 9:30 and so on. How to rewrite the rule to get the planning by quarters?

Comment: Change 3600000 to 900000

Comment: Thanks. Just by logic it seems to be wrong math but it does the trick. Wanna turn it into an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `3600000` (1 hour = 3600 seconds = 3600000 milliseconds) to `900000` (15 minutes = 900 seconds = 900000 milliseconds).